# my angularJS file upload is not work. it shows bad request error. how to solve it? I am using java spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

**mainRought.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngFileUpload','angularFileUpload','ui.grid','ui.bootstrap','ngCookies','ngResource','angular-media-preview','ngComboBox']);
```

**my curdopration.js**

```
myApp.controller('curdopration', function($scope, $http , $modal , $location , $rootScope , $window , $upload, CustomerService) {

$scope.addUser=function(registrationData)
    {
        $upload.upload({
                    url : _path + '/cityController/addUser',
                    data : registrationData,
                    file : userImage,
                    method : "POST",
                    /*headers : "content-type=multipart/*"*/
                })  
    }
});
```

**citycontroller.java**

```
[@RequestMapping(value="/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
    public @ResponseBody void addUser(@RequestBody curdOpration curdopration,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        System.out.println("Countryname"+curdopration.toString());
        cityService.addUser(curdopration);
    }][1]
```

**my browser shows** 
POST http://localhost:8081/demopeoject/cityController/addUser 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Errors inside your webserver ?

Comment: error is inside web console ... it is not allow to upload file into my java controller from angularjs controller... my normal data are transferred successfully using post only image file has problem.

Comment: $http.post(_path + '/cityController/addUser',registrationData)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $modal.open({ template: '<div class="modal-body"><div class="text-success text-center"><h4><i class="fa fa-check"></i> User Added Successfully !!!</h4></div></div>' });
    $window.location.href ="#index";
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $upload.upload instead of $http.post in your angular code.

```
$upload.upload({
    url : 'saveUserData',
    file : yourFile,
    data : $scope.userDataBean,
    method : 'POST'
});
```

Change your spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUserData", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))
public @ResponseBody String saveUserDataAndFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, UserDataBean userDataBean) {
    System.out.println("output: " + userDataBean.toString());
    return "";
}
```